# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "Befehl" und "Kommando"?

Tags: difference

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen *Befehl* und *Kommando*, speziell in der Programmierung? Ich habe sowohl *Befehlszeile* als auch *Kommandozeile* gesehen.

Comment: Ich habe verschiedenen Rechtschreibfehler korrigiert. Der Singular ist Befehl,  Plural Befehle.  Befehls ist falsch! Bei den Kommas bin ich mir nicht sicher.

Comment: Das Englische "both X and Y" übersetzt man am besten mit "sowohl ... als auch", dann hat man auch kein Problem mit Kommas @Iris ;)

Comment: Was sagt das Wörterbuch? WIeso ist dessen Antwort nicht ausreichend?

Comment: @Iris: Plural von „Komma“ ist eigentlich „Kommata“, standardsprachlich aber auch einfach „Kommas“.

Comment: Mir fällt jetzt erst auf, dass ich mit "Kommandozeile" ausschließlich Windows' cmd verbinde. In der Programmierung kenne ich eigentlich nur "Befehl" und "Anweisung". Und "Kommando" eigentlich gar nicht (als C#-Entwickler gibt's noch die "Commands", die ich aber gar nicht eindeutsche).

Answer (score 6):

*Kommando* ist im Kontext der Programmierung eher als Eindeutschung des englischen *command* zu verstehen. *Befehl* ist der korrekte Begriff und wird auch geläufiger verwendet.

Allgemein hat *Kommando* aber mehrere, überwiegend militärische, Bedeutungen:

1. kurzer (militärischer) Befehl/Auftrag
2. Leitung/Befehlsgewalt bei der Durchführung eines (militärischen) Auftrags
3. Gruppe, die zur Bewältigung einer Aufgabe bestimmt ist

*Befehl* wird zwar auch im Militär genutzt (selbe Bedeutung wie die 1. Bedeutung von *Kommando*), ist jedoch in der Programmierung eher vertreten.

(Quelle: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Kommando, angepasst und vereinfacht)

Comment: Der Aspekt der Kürze ist meines Erachtens wichtig zur Unterscheidung. Ein Befehl kann lang und komplex sein und wird häufig als (Imperativ-)Satz geäußert. Ein Kommando ist kurz und oft konventionalisiert bzw. standardisiert, kann aus einem einzigen (nicht verbalen) Wort bestehen. Im Computerkontext erwarte ich von einem Befehl, dass er Parameter / Argumente / Optionen unterstützt, von einem Kommando eher nicht. Daneben gibt es noch die **Anweisungen** sowie in der Programmierung **Funktionen** und **Methoden**.

Comment: @Crissov: Was ist denn ein nichtverbales Wort? Formulierungen wie '... erwarte ich ...' macht die Sprache zur Privat- und Geschmackssache. Wir suchen aber hier doch im Gegenteil nach allgemeinverbindlichen Aussagen.

Comment: @falkb Sagt irgendjemand _Kommandoparameter_ oder _Kommandooption_? Dass _Kommandozeile_ ein etablierter „falscher Freund“ ist, wurde hier schon erwähnt. @userunknown Ich habe etwas flapsig versucht „kein Verb“ als Adjektiv zu schreiben, man darf _nicht verbal_ aber auch auf `ls` und ähnlich kryptisches bezogen verstehen, und habe bewusst einen Kommentar und keine Antwort geschrieben.

Comment: *Anweisungen* sind dasselbe wie *Befehle*, das ist synonm, genauso wie das Wort *Instruktion*. (Maschinenbefehle, Maschineninstruktionen etc. ist alles synonym) Der Begriff der *Methode* kommt nur in der objektorientierten Programmierung vor, ansonsten heißen Funktionen ohne Rückgabewert *Prozeduren*. Funktionen und Prozeduren können auch als *Unterprogramm* bezeichnet werden. @Crissov

Comment: Was soll eigentlich "ist eher als Eindeutschung zu verstehen" bedeuten? Eher als was? Was heißt "wird geläufiger verwendet"? Häufiger? "Mir ist ein Begriff geläufig", aber "wird geläufiger verwendet"? Die Unterschiede außerhalb der Programmierung sind zwar gegeben, aber die Frage fokussierte ja eindeutig auf den Kontext Programmieren - dazu leistet die Antwort keinen Beitrag. Thema verfehlt.

Answer (score 4):

Ein Befehl ist eine verbindliche Anweisung. Kommando ist eigentlich etwas weiter gefasst. Neben seiner Bedeutung als Synonym für Befehl kann es auch für die Instanz stehen, die Befehle erteilt, bzw. für die Befehlsgewalt an sich.<sup>[(1)](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Kommando)</sup>

In der Programmierung ist es egal, ob man Befehl oder Kommando sagt, da mit Kommando immer das Synonym zu Befehl gemeint ist. Es wird eine auszuführende Anweisung an den Prozessor oder an einen Interpreter gegeben.

Comment: "Wer hat hier den Befehl" ist auch weiter gefasst.

Comment: @userunknown: Richtig. Kann jedoch nicht auf Personen ausgeweitet werden wie bei Kommando.

Answer (score 1):

**Befehl** ist ein Wort mit langer Geschichte in der deutschen Sprache (http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?lemma=Befehl), definitiv ein deutsches Wort: Der althochdeutsche Wortstamm *"(p)felh / velh"* kommt häufiger vor, lässt sich heute noch im Sinne von *"Senden"*, *"Von sich geben"* übersetzen (*"Mit besten Empfehlungen"*, *"Das Ziel verfehlt"*).

**Kommando** hingegen trägt lateinische Wurzeln, *mandare* wird auch hier i.S.v. *"Senden"* verwandt (wobei das Senden von Post, also das klassische Senden, stets mit *mittere* übersetzt werden würde). Weitere Verwendung findet der lateinische Stamm u.a. in *Mandat* und *Mandant* (*"Auftrag"* und *"Auftraggeber"*).

Es lässt sich anhand der hier aufgezählten Beispiele feststellen, dass für *(p)fehl* und *mand* stets die **Quelle der Information besonders hervorgehoben** wird.

- *"Ziel verfehlt"*: die Ursache ist der Schütze, nicht das Ziel oder die Flugbahn
- *"Beste Empfehlungen"*: Der Absender schätzt die Sendung besonders hoch, eine wahre Aussage über den "Waren"wert oder die Wertschätzung des Empfängers ist nicht enthalten
- *"tramandare" (ital.)*: vererben, i.d.R. ohne Einflussnahme des Empfängers

**Fazit:** Beide Wörter existieren bereits seit Langem und wurden in beiden Sprachgruppen (romanisch und  deutsch) für gleiche Sachverhalte verwendet. Sie können als Synonyme betrachtet werden. Auch Programmiersprachen sollten das in der Form berücksichtigen, bei abgewandeltem Einsatz ist eine aus dem Zusammenhang gerissene Erklärung natürlich nicht mehr möglich.

Answer (score -1):

Beim Programmieren ist man mit *Befehl* generell auf der sicheren Seite:

- Befehlszeile
- Assemblerbefehl (hier ist mir Kommando praktisch nie begegnet)

*Command prompt* ist etwas sperrig; die übliche Übersetzung ist *Eingabeaufforderung* oder im Windows-Kontext auch (noch) *DOS-Fenster*.

Comment: Ich empfinde *Eingabeaufforderung* hauptsächlich als missglückten Versuch Microsofts, einen neutralen Neologismus zu schaffen, mal abgesehen davon, dass praktisch jedes Programm zur Eingabe von irgendwas auffordert, eben nicht nur die sogenannte *Eingabeaufforderung*. Entsprechend ist mein Eindruck auch eher, dass der Begriff *Eingabeaufforderung* tendenziell eher "unter Zwang" benutzt wird, und zwar, wenn es konkret darum geht, das Ding im Windows-Startmenü wiederzufinden. Eigentlich *üblicher* ist neben dem beschreibenden *DOS-Fenster* auch *Konsole*.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Programme im Batch-Betrieb oder andere Daemons erwarten keine Eingabe des Benutzers.

Comment: @Robert: Stimmt, nur sind diese Programme auch diejenigen, mit denen ausgerechnet die Benutzer, die am ehesten im Startmenü dem Begriff *Eingabeaufforderung* begegnen wohl am wenigstens in Berührung kommen ;)

Comment: Bei Windows95 gab es ein DOS-Fenster. Die Oberfläche sah zwar so aus wie das User-Interface für cmd.exe oder cmd32.exe, aber ist etwas inhaltlich verschiedenes. Bei Win98 oder XP ist das Dos-Fenster m.W. dann ganz verschwunden. Ein Kommandozeileninterface gibt es nach wie vor, aber das Ding als DOS-Fenster zu bezeichnen ist schlicht falsch; eine Weigerung die Tatsache zu akzeptieren, dass es nicht das gleiche ist und damit eine Quelle von Missverständnissen für die, die es glauben.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Die *Eingabeaufforderung* ist einfach die Übersetzung von *Command Prompt*. Letzteres ist m. E. auch im Englischen ein schlechter Begriff für *Konsole* oder *Terminal*. Das *prompt* ist an sich nur das Zeichen vor dem Cursor wie `>`, `$`, `#`.

Comment: @nwellnhof: Na ja, *Eingabe* ist ja schon noch mal eine Stufe allgemeiner als *command*, was eben spezieller bzw. begrenzter als allgemein *input* ist.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Ja, *Eingabeaufforderung* ist nur die Übersetzung von *prompt*. Die Anwendung *Command Prompt* müsste dann wörtlich übersetzt *Befehlseingabeaufforderung* heißen.

Answer (score -1):

Keine, die sind nahezu gleichwertig. Ältere Personen werden sich vielleicht unter `Kommandozeile` weniger vorstellen können; sie werden sich mit der `Befehlszeile` wahrscheinlich genauso wenig auskennen, aber da könnten sie sie eher deuten und wenn man gemein ist, dürfte die Deutung möglicherweise auch die falsche sein.

Comment: Wieso können sie Befehlszeile eher deuten als Kommandozeile? Ab welchem Alter sind die Leute 'älter'; älter als wer oder was? Ist es nicht so, dass gerade ältere Leute, die noch DOS erlebt haben, eher wissen, was das ist, als jüngere die nur IPhone und Android kennen?

Comment: Ja, es gibt sicher ältere Menschen, die sich sehr gut auskennen, aber fragen Sie mal eine ältere Dame oder einen älteren Herren (70++) - ganz zufällig  - auf der Strasse, was eine Kommandozeile ist?

Comment: @Vienna Hilfreicher Hinweis: mit einen @ und einem Benutzernamen kann man Benutzer pingen (also benachrichtigen, dass geantwortet wurde) wie ich es am Anfang dieses Kommentars getan habe. Hätte ich aber nicht müssen, denn Postbesitzer (in diesem Fall du) werden automatisch gepingt. Re Ältere: Ich glaube, dass dein 70-jähriger Beispielsherr auch die Befehlszeile falsch parsen würde.

Comment: @Jan: Ist parsen nicht einfach nur das Abtasten nach Wortgrenzen und dergleichen? Die Fragestellung hier ist doch das Interpretieren des Wortes.